# show the select value in other input text laravel

Tags: php, laravel

hello there i have this code

```
<td class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
                      <select class="form-control text-center" name="grade">
                       <option>Grad</option>        
                          @foreach($salarys as $salay)          
                                        <option value="{{ $salay->grade}}">{{ $salay->grade}}</option>              
                           @endforeach   
                     </select>                        
                   </td>

                   <td class="col-sm-3">
                     <input type="text"    class="form-control text-center" value="500" ="" placeholder="Net Pay"  name="netpay" readonly>
                   </td>
```

what i wanna to show the value in the other text value of 500 for example if i select something like grade A so i wanna to see what i select in the other text

like grade A has 500 net pay or net salary

so i wanna to see the

netpay instead  of the  value="500"

so salray

{{ $salay->grade}}this in the select box A, B ,C
if i select one of them i wanna to see the net pay in the other 
input text 
{{ $salay->netpay}} this is the net pay 500 , 800 , 900

Answer (score 0):

If you need to see what you have selected in the text box you can use jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('select[name="grade"]').change(function() {
        $('input[name="netpay"]').val($(this,':selected').val())
    })
})
```

If you need some display related data to what you have selected, you should make an ajax call and then add the result value in text box.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **data-attribute**

```
<td class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
  <select id="selGrade" class="form-control text-center" data-grade="{{$salary->grade}}" name="grade">
    <option>Grad</option>        
       @foreach($salarys as $salay)          
    <option value="{{ $salay->grade}}">{{ $salay->grade}}</option>              
@endforeach
```

```
<td class="col-sm-3">
  <input id="netpay" type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="500" ="" placeholder="Net Pay"  name="netpay" readonly>
</td>
```

In your Jquery

```
$(function () {

    $('#selGrade').change(function() {
        $var = $(#selGrade).attr('data-grade')
        $('#netpay').val($var)
    })
})
```

Very old solution but i think this will work :) 
Hope this help ...